# Can JGroups be exported to Iran?

Tags: jgroups

Would I be able to use JGroups library in an application that would go to Iran?

I've found some encryption related code:
***org.jgroups.protocols.ENCRYPT.class***

**A more precise question, is the code above using or providing any encryption algorithm? If so what is the length of the used encryption keys?**

And this seams to be prohibited by American regulations (e.g. Export Commodity Control Number (ECCN) 5D002.c.1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted Red Hat Legal and here's their response:

"Red Hat's software (including open source community projects) may **not  be exported, re-exported or transferred**, either directly or indirectly, to the embargoed countries: Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Sudan & Syria.

Red Hat's export policies and guidelines: https://www.redhat.com/en/about/export-control-product-matrix."

Regarding your other question: no, the encryption code in JGroups isn't using a specific algorithm; these are defined via attributes in the protocol and provided by specific security providers, e.g. BouncyCastle.

JGroups itself, however, is not written against a specific provider, but against the generic JCE in JDK.